# Delegation Deposit

Tags: wallet, transaction

When delegating for the first time there is a 2 ADA deposit being spent.

Is this 2 ADA ever returned? if yes when is it returned and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be returned. 2 ADA is the current cost of registering your staking key on chain (this is to prevent sybil attacks). If and when you [de-register](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/cardano-node-cli-reference.md) your staking keys, the 2 ADA is returned to the original address it was sent from.

Comment: thanks, eventually I found the unstake option in ccvault.io in the wallets settings, scroll down.